# How to avoid a column or row size on resizing tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am having trouble on resizing the column and row frames in tkinter.
[image]

I have divided column and row in 1:4 ratio. On resizing the window it maintains the ratio but I want to avoid resizing of black and the red frames. So basically, when I resize, the black and red frames should not grow or contract but all the changes happen in the white window. How can I achieve that ?

Code -

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_geometry("1200x700")

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=4)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=4)

f1 = tk.Frame(root, background="black", height=100, width=100)
f2 = tk.Frame(root, background="black", height=100, width=100)
f3 = tk.Frame(root, background="red", height=100, width=100)
f4 = tk.Frame(root, background="white", height=100, width=100)

f1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
f2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
f3.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
f4.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Simply specify the height of black frame and width of red frame, then set weight=1 for column 1 and row 1.

Comment: This does not work, all frames are equally sized due to 1:1 ratio

Comment: Did you set weight=1 for only column=1 and row=1 (i.e. to expand only the white frame)?

Comment: Ohh yes, it works! My bad .. Did not comment the grid_configure for row=0 and column=0. Great !! Just tried, grid_propagate(1) for f1, f2 and f3 and it also works.

Comment: Also you can combine f1 and f2 into one frame and use `columnspan=2`.

Comment: You need to call `f3.grid_propagate(0)`.

Comment: Just remove `grid_columnconfigure` and `grid_rowconfigure` for column 0 and row 0, this way they will keep there size and only row 1 and column 1 will get resized

Answer (score 3):

As I understood, you want:

- column *0* - to keep its width,
- row *0* - to keep its heigth.

But your code sets configuration is such a way that on each resize:

- 1/5 of the size increase will be "given" to column *0*,
- 4/5 of the size increase will be "given" to column *1*,
- the same for rows.

The proper solution, using *grid*, is to:

- leave the default weight of *0* for column and row *0*,
- specify any positive width for column and row *1*.

So change the respective part of your code to:

```
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pack` geometry manager to obtain the resizable window geometry you desire:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_geometry("1200x700")

f1 = tk.Frame(root, bg="black", height=100)
f1.pack(anchor=tk.N, fill=tk.X)

f2 = tk.Frame(root)

f3 = tk.Frame(f2, bg="red", width=100)
f3.pack(anchor=tk.NW, side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)

f4 = tk.Frame(f2, bg="blue", width=100, height=100)
f4.pack(anchor=tk.NW, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

f2.pack(anchor=tk.N, side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Actually I want to use grid and not pack or place. Got my answers in the comment. Thankyou : )

Comment: Oh, okay, no trouble, that was not specified in the question.